# Problems creating bottom Navbar Android Studio

Tags: java, android, navigationbar, androidx

I've been trying for a few days to create a bottom navbar for my app but for some reason its just not showing up in the design view. Doesn't really help the fact that not alot of tutorials that use AndroidX library

(Excuse me if i'm not using the right words to describe things)

Tried changing the size on the design, tweaking the dependencies and retrying numerous times.

```
/// build.gradle file


buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
/// Build.gradle(Module:app)


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.runwithmeapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.19.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'


}
```

```
/// XML for activity


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    tools:context=".BottomNav">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

```
/// XML for my menu

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
        android:title="Map"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:title="Profile"/>


</menu>
```

Right now what i want to happen is that i can just see the design properly at the bottom of the activity but it just isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I've created something very similar. In the Design, for me it doesn't show up at the bottom. Instead, it's showing up at the top (Action Bar). But when I compile and build the project and run it on the emulator or device, it's showing up as a bottom navigation bar.

In my **MainActivity.java**, I'm loading it with this piece of code:

```
//show bottom navigation bar
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not specifying a fixed height instead use wrap_content in BottomNavigationView. Also Relativelayout is deprecated use Constraintlayout instead.

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/item_background"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/item_tint"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/item_text_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```